# Orientable surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Suppose that two smooth surfaces $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ are diffeomorphic and that $S$ is orientable.

I want to prove that $\tilde{S}$ is orientable.

$$$$

Since $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ are diffeomorphic, we have that there is a smooth map between these two surfaces, which is a bijection and the inverse is also smooth.

We have that $S$ is orientable, then there is a smooth choice of unit normal at any point of $S$.

Do we conclude then that $\tilde{S}$ is also orientable because of the fact that there is a bijective map between $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

A surface $S$ is orientable if there exists an atlas $A$ for $S$ with the property that, if $\Phi$ is the transition map between any two surface patches in $A$, then $\det (J(\Phi )) > 0$ where $\Phi$ is defined.

An oriented surface is a surface $S$ together with a smooth choice of unit normal $N$ at each point, i.e., a smooth map $N : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$
(meaning that each of the three components of $N$ is a smooth function $S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) such that, for all $p \in S, \ N(p)$ is a unit vector perpendicular to $T_pS$. Any oriented surface is orientable!

$$$$

---

$$$$

[image]

Comment: In your textbook, what's the definition of "orientable". If the definition says something about a "smooth choice of unit normal", then what's the definition of a "smooth choice"?

Comment: I added the definition and a proposition of the book at my initial post... Could you take a look at it? @bubba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your first definition of orientable, let 
$$\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}_{i \in I}
$$ 
be an atlas for $S$ satisfying the orientation requirement. To be clear on the notation, $U_i \subset S$ is open and $\phi_i : U_i \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a homeomorphism, and the orientation requirement says that each overlap map
$$\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1} : \phi_i(U_i \cap U_j) \to \phi_j(U_i \cap U_j)
$$
is a diffeomorphism having positive Jacobian determinant at each point of its domain.

Suppose that $f : S \to \tilde S$ is a differeomorphism. Then it's pretty straightforward to show that
$$\{(f(U_i),\phi_i \circ f^{-1})\}_{i \in I}
$$
is an atlas for $\tilde S$ satisfying the orientation requirement.

Comment: By "overlap map" do you mean "transition map" ?

Comment: Yes, those are synonyms.

Comment: You say that the orientation requirement says that each overlap map $\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1} : \phi_i(U_i \cap U_j) \to \phi_j(U_i \cap U_j)$ is a diffeomorphism. Why is it a **diffeomorphism** ? Does it stand by definition?

Comment: The transition map $\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}$ is a smooth map; that is part of the definition of an atlas. It's inverse map is $\phi_i \circ \phi_j^{-1}$, and this map is also a transition map in the atlas, so it is also smooth. The map $\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}$ is therefore a diffeomorphism, since it and its inverse are both smooth.

Comment: At which point do we need the diffeomorphism of the overlap map?

Comment: Is the atlas for $\tilde{S}$ the following? $$\tilde{\Phi}: (f\circ \sigma_i )(U_i\cap U_j)\rightarrow (f\circ \sigma_j )(U_i\cap U_j)\\ \tilde{\Phi}=(f\circ \sigma_j)\circ (f\circ \sigma_i)^{-1}=f\circ \sigma_j\circ \sigma_i^{-1}\circ f^{-1} \\ \Rightarrow \tilde{\Phi}=f\circ \Phi\circ f^{-1}$$ ?

Comment: How can we show then that $\det (J(\tilde{\Phi}))>0$ ?

Comment: $f \circ \sigma_i$ does not make sense. The range of $\sigma_i$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ whereas the domain of $f$ is $S$.

Comment: Ah ok... Is the range of $f^{-1}$ equal to the domain of $f$ ?

Comment: I added in my initial post a proposition of my book... Could you take a look at it? Why can we take in that case $f \circ \sigma_1$ ?

Comment: That proposition looks like what you need to answer your question. I notice that your $\sigma_i$'s go in the opposite direction than my $\phi_i$'s, that is, $\sigma_i = \phi_i^{-1}$. I could perhaps rewrite my answer, but that would have to wait unitl later.

Comment: Let $\{(U_i,\sigma_i)\}_{i \in I}$ be an atlas for $S$, where $U_i \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is open and $\sigma_i : U_i \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a homeomorphism. 
Let $$\Phi=\sigma^{-1}_j \circ \sigma_i : \sigma^{-1}_i(\sigma_i(U_i) \cap \sigma_j(U_j)) \to \sigma^{-1}_j(\sigma_i(U_i) \cap \sigma_j(U_j))
$$ be the overlap map. 
Since $S$ is orientable, we have that the Jacobian determinant of the overlaap map is positive at each point of its domain.

Comment: Suppose that $f : S \to \tilde S$ is a differeomorphism. Then $\{(f(U_i),f\circ\sigma_i)\}_{i \in I}$
is an atlas for $\tilde S$. 

The transition map is defined as follows: $$\tilde{\Phi}: (f\circ \sigma_i )^{-1}((f\circ \sigma_i )(U_i)\cap (f\circ \sigma_i )(U_j))\rightarrow (f\circ \sigma_j )^{-1}((f\circ \sigma_i )(U_i)\cap (f\circ \sigma_i )(U_j))\\ \tilde{\Phi}=(f\circ \sigma_j)^{-1}\circ (f\circ \sigma_i)=\sigma_j^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\circ f \circ  \sigma_i=\sigma_j^{-1}\circ  \sigma_i \\ \Rightarrow \tilde{\Phi}= \Phi$$

Comment: So $\det (J(\tilde{\Phi}))=\det (J(\Phi ))>0$, at each point of the domain of $\tilde{\Phi}$. Therefore, $\tilde{S}$ is orientable. $$$$ 
Is everything correct?

Comment: Given that $f : S \to S$ and $\sigma_i : U_i \to \mathbb{R}^3$, the expression $f \circ \sigma_i$ still does not make sense, for the same reason I wrote before.

Comment: $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the range of $\sigma_i$ is also a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, right? So, why does $f\circ\sigma_i$ not make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34359/discussion-between-lee-mosher-and-mary-star).

Answer (score 5):

In general, an orientation is not exactly a ``smooth choice of unit normal''. This definition is only really helpful for 2D surfaces embedded in 3D. I'm guessing that you need to consider more general manifolds. The best way to generalise is as follows. The normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ to a 2D surface in 3D is really a machine that maps pairs of tangent vectors to the triple product, $(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}) \to \mathbf{n}\cdot(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v})$. If this is positive, $(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{n})$ is a right-handed set. Otherwise left-handed. In this spirit, we have the following definition.

**Defn.** An n-manifold $M$ is *orientable* if it admits a global, non-vanishing n-form $\omega$, called the *volume form*.

So an orientation is a recipe for turning $n$ tangent vectors into a number. If the number is positive, your vectors are positively oriented. Otherwise negatively oriented.

Now suppose that $S$ is orientable with volume form $\omega$ and $\phi: S \to \tilde{S}$ is your diffeomorphism. Then $\phi^{-1}: \tilde{S}\to S$ is also a diffeomorphism. Moreover the pullback of $\omega$ to $\tilde{S}$, $$\omega'= \phi^{-1 *} \omega$$
defines a global, non-vanishing n-form on $\tilde{S}$ (if it vanished anywhere, $\phi^{-1}_{*}$ would be taking a tangent vector to $0$, which contradicts $\phi^{-1}$ being a diffeomorphism) We conclude that $\tilde{S}$ is orientable.

Alternatively, using your vector intuition, we could note that $\phi_{*}$ has full rank on every tangent space and varies smoothly over $S$, so a smooth choice of $n$ tangent vectors on S (another definition of ``orientation'') maps to another such choice on $\tilde{S}$. Hope that helps!

Comment: Along very similar lines, you could show that a diffeomorphism $\phi:S \to \tilde{S}$ induces an isomorphism $D\phi: T^*S \to T^*\tilde{S}$, and orientability on a smooth manifold $X$ is exactly the condition that its determinant bundle is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

A surface is not orientable if and only if it contains a Möbius band embedded. This property is invariant by diffeomorphims or homeomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by "the surface contains a Möbius band **embedded**" ?

Comment: A subset that is homeomorphic to a Möbius strip (here an open subset)

Comment: In my book there is a proof why the Möbius strip is not orientable. But why is every surface that is homeomorphic to a Möbius strip not orientable? Is it because of the homeomorphism?

Comment: A nonorientable surface contains an orientation-reversing loop, and you can then check that if you thicken this loop inside the surface you get a Mobius strip.

Comment: I see... Thanks!! :-) @DanielMcLaury